# Unimodality of length of longest increasing subsequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, unimodality

For $w \in S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ letters, let $\mathrm{is}(w)$ denote the length of the longest increasing subsequence of $w$. Define, $g_n(p) := |\{w \in S_n \colon \mathrm{is}(w) = p\}|$. Is it true that for fixed $n$, the sequence $g_n(1),g_n(2),\ldots,g_n(n)$ is unimodal? Is this somewhere in the literature?

For example, for $n=7$ we have the sequence $1, 428, 2332, 1821, 421, 36, 1$.

EDIT:

For more on this question (which remains open), see [this nice survey of Novak and Rhoades](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.13146).

Comment: did you already look at: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C428%2C2332%2C1821%2C421%2C36%2C1.&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @Suvrit: I don't see where unimodality is mentioned on that OEIS page (or in the references).

Comment: I did not chase those refs, so was wondering if you had already done so :-)

Comment: did you try proving log-concavity instead?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: Good question- I have not thought about this. Also I have subsequently learned that this unimodality question has been considered by others (e.g. Greta Panova), but think it is still open.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: In fact, I just learned today of a paper of Bill Chen from 2008 that explicitly conjectures log-concavity: https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3392

Comment: @SamHopkins: Thanks for letting me know. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

The length of the longest increasing subsequence of a random permutation is tightly concentrated, so I would be surprised if this were not true for large $n$.  A proof of concentration using Talagrand's inequality is in Alon and Spencer, and they mention that [Baik, Deift and Johansson](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1999-12-04/S0894-0347-99-00307-0/S0894-0347-99-00307-0.pdf) determined the distribution asymptotically.  Perhaps you can read out something strong enough for your purposes from there.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the reference. Somehow this strikes me as simple enough as not to require all the machinery of Talagrand, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: The asymptotic density (i.e., when $n\to \infty$) is the Tracy-Widom distribution, which is unimodal. This of course does not imply that the actual distribution is unimodal - 
there could conceivably exist other local maxima somewhere in the tails. As to whether you can do without Talagrand's inequalities - just for concentration, you can do with the limit results of Kerov-Vershik and Logan-Shepp; however, the estimate of variance using Talagrand's inequalities held the record until the BDJ work.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have the identity
$$
\sum_{\pi \in S_n} t^{is(\pi)} = \sum_{\lambda \vdash n} (f^{\lambda})^2t^{\lambda_1},
$$
by using RSK and Greene's theorem.
By using the hook formula, one can then easily check your conjecture for $n \leq 40$ in Mathematica.

My guess is that
$$
\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \log(f^{\lambda}) t^{\lambda_1}
$$
is unimodal.

*Greene, Curtis*, [**An extension of Schensted’s theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(74)90031-0), Adv. Math. 14, 254-265 (1974). [ZBL0303.05006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0303.05006).

Comment: In fact, no need to appeal to Greene's result here, which concerns the entire shape of the RS tableau: Schensted knew that $\lambda_1$ is LIS.